# Polymer paper element attributes and Angular

Tags: angular, polymer

I am using Angular and Google Polymer paper elements. Works fine, but I have problems with attributes. While this does work:

```
<paper-card>{{someVarFromComponent}}</paper-card>
```

This does NOT:

```
<paper-card heading="{{someVarFromComponent}}"></paper-card>
```

`someVarFromComponent` is a variable of my component. It seems providing variables to templates does not work in the parameters. Or it does not work in parameters for polymer components?

I need to change the content of the `heading` attribute in `<paper-card>` when my component variable `someVarFromComponent` changes.

Is there a solution or workaround for this problem?

Comment: It might be necessary to enable full shadow DOM for Polymer to work properly with Angular https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/settings.html

Comment: It works for me [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/jMNExeWhy9stK3XAxtPo?p=preview). (not familiarized with polymer, but I think it's working).

Comment: can you add more code? How you define `someVarFromComponent`?

Comment: Can you provide more information so that we can better answer your question and give it the answer it deserves.

Answer (score 2):

As Günter stated in his comment, most likely full shadow DOM support will need to be turned on to work with angular2. By default this is not enabled. Shadow DOM can be enabled by using

```
<script>
    window.Polymer = window.Polymer || {};
    window.Polymer.dom = 'shadow';
</script>
```

in the `<head>` of your `index.html` file or can be used without the `<script>` tags in your startup js file (preferably the first piece of code that is executed.

Comment: Enabling full shadow DOM is advisable in general when Polymer is used together with Angular2. I built an example project from the code in the question and it works fine even with default shady DOM (like @ErikMartinez demonstrated with his Plunker)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ah, so possibly something else at fault here. I'll leave this here for historical reasons, but may remove as with your comment it does appear to not be the correct answer to the question.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's some issue with the general setup. But @Witek didn't provide any additional information which makes it hard to point down.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Agreed, I've asked for more information so hopefully he will provide some, but as it stands, this question in unanswerable due to not enough details.

Answer (score 0):

try this
`<paper-card [heading]="someVarFromComponent"></paper-card>`

Comment: This does not work at all. The header ist always empty. Even if I initialize someVarFromComponent with text on declaration.